# How to combine elements in set and a string to a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

Have got a *set()* like

```
item = {'Apple','Lemon'}
```

and a string `flow='Mango'`
need to combine both to form a list like below

```
result = ['Mango','Apple','Lemon']
```

tried the code `result = [flow ,item]` which doesn't work out.
Help me through this. Thanks!

Comment: What does the question have to do with pandas? Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the set into a new list that includes `flow`:

```
result = [flow, *item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add item to the set, conver the set to a list:

```
item.add(flow)
list(item)
# ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Lemon']
```

Or convert the set to a list and concatenate it with a list of `flow`:

```
[flow] + list(item)
# ['Mango', 'Apple', 'Lemon']
```

The second approach preserves the original set.